# Angular Material Snackbar not work properly

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm using a snackbar to tell users some information, but the snackbar does not perform at right position, Here is my code:

`openSnackBar(msg: string) {
    this.snackBar.open(msg, undefined, {
      duration: 2000,
      extraClasses:['snack-bar']
    });
  }`

`this.snackBar`is injected in constructor

when I call this function the snackbar perform at my page's left-down corner, like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBH7C.jpg)

you see the black block with text is the snackbar, and add a div with same text on it, and this div does not disappear anymore.

I'm using bootstrap3 + Angular 5 + Material 2

Answer (score 0):

For right positioning, set the configuration `horizontalPosition: 'right'`
In your code,

```
this.snackBar.open(msg, undefined, {
  duration: 2000,
  horizontalPosition:'right'
});
```